# Py.test loop through the tests repeatedly

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to repeat the tests N number of times (same tests that are collected).

Why: By doing do I want to see if the speed of the tests decreases or I can collect the "average time" of one parameter then pass the other parameter and get the "average time" again.

My understanding is to use `def pytest_runtestloop()` hook, however I have troubles with it.

Here is my code for the hook:

```
def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    repeat = int(session.config.option.repeat)
    assert isinstance(repeat, int), "Repeat must be an integer"
    for i in range(repeat): #@UnusedVariable                      
        session.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("main").pytest_runtestloop(session)

    return True
```

The problem is that it the **"setups" are run only the first time**:
For example:

```
class TestSomething(object):

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope = "class", autouse = True)
    def setup(self):
        //setup function

    def test_something(self):
        //test function
```

Here `setup` will be called during the first cycle only, and `test_something` would be called both times if I set `session.config.option.repeat` to 2

What am I doing wrong? Is there better approach?

Answer (score 2):

It seems pytest-2.3.4 is keeping some state internally that keeps fixtures from running again.  `pytest_runtest_loop` was not written with your use case in mind.  You may file a "bug" issue about it and we can see what we can do to fix it.  (I quickly looked but couldn't immediately see what was going wrong, requires more exploring).